# Why do "unlocked" items appear disabled after scrolling?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I've written a custom adapter (`LevelAdapter` because I am showing a list of levels of a game) that populates a `ListView` fragment from a list of dummy objects.  Each dummy object possesses a boolean "unlocked" property and I am attempting to conditionally disable and set some styling properties on each item in the list depending on whether the underlying dummy item is "unlocked" or not.  To that end, I have also employed a `ViewHolder`.

The code below works fine until the user scrolls down and back up, at which point the "unlocked" items don't become disabled, but they do lose their appropriate styling.

```
public class LevelAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DummyContent.DummyItem> {
    private List<DummyContent.DummyItem> objects;
    private DummyContent.DummyItem item;
    private Context context;
    private int textViewResourceId;
    private int resource;

    public LevelAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<DummyContent.DummyItem> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.objects = objects;
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.textViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;

    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
        int position;
        boolean unlocked;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;


        // https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(resource, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) v.findViewById(textViewResourceId);
            holder.position = position;
            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        item = objects.get(position);
        holder.text.setText(item.title);

        if (item.unlocked == false) {
            holder.text.setTextColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            Typeface type = Typeface.create("", Typeface.ITALIC);
            holder.text.setTypeface(type);
        }

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return true; // technically untrue, but a hack to show the line divider between items
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {

        item = objects.get(position);
        if (item.unlocked == true) {
            return true;
        } else {

            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if (item.unlocked == false) {
        holder.text.setTextColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        Typeface type = Typeface.create("", Typeface.ITALIC);
        holder.text.setTypeface(type);
    }
```

You should create else statement for `unlocked == true` case.

Now if adapter gets view to reuse that had an item with unlocked false to fill with item that has unlocked true it won't change a style but keep the old one.

Comment: Works:

`} else {
            holder.text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            Typeface type = Typeface.create("", Typeface.NORMAL);
            holder.text.setTypeface(type);
        }`